# Bounding an expectation involving i.i.d. standard Gaussians and Rademacher

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, expectation

I have tried to bound the following quantity, but cannot get the "right" (conjectured) bound:
$$
\phi(\gamma,d,n) = -1+e^{\frac{1}{2}n\gamma^2 d}
 \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\frac{\mathbb{E}_Z[\prod_{j=1}^n(1+\gamma\langle X^{(j)},Z\rangle)]^2}{\prod_{i=1}^d \cosh(\gamma\sum _{j=1}^nX^{(j)}_i)}\right]\tag{1}$$
where $\gamma\in(0,1]$, $d\gg 1$, $X=(X^{(j)})_{1\leq j\leq n}$ is a collection of i.i.d. standard $d$-dimensional Gaussian r.v.'s, and $Z$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}^d$ (Rademacher) independent of the $X^{(j)}$'s.

> **Conjecture.** Assuming $\gamma^2 d \leq 1$, as long as  $n\gamma^4 d \ll 1$ we have
>   $$\phi(\gamma,d,n)\ll 1\tag{2}$$

I haven't been able to show it, even for $n=2$; there seems to be a delicate balancing act for things to exactly cancel the $e^{\frac{1}{2}n\gamma^2 d}$ factor...

---

**Update:** For (1) in the case $n=2$, my numerical experiments (a bit noisier than I had hoped) seem to be consistent with the conjecture:

- $\gamma$ fixed, varying $d$
  [image]
- $d=5$ fixed, varying $\gamma$ (fit made with SciPy, in Python)
  [image]

**Update 2:** For $d=1$ and $n\in\{1,2,3\}$, Mathematica could compute explicitly the expectation (though already it takes some time for $n=3$. The behavior on these few points is clearly linear wrt $n$:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is $Y$ in $E_{XY}$ a misprint or some other r.v. $Y$ is, indeed, present?

Comment: @fedja Oh, good catch, that was a remain of what I wrote in an earlier version for $n=2$ (I had $X,Y$ instead of $X_1,X_2$). Edited.

Comment: One more stupid question: when $n=d=1$ we have $E_X(\frac {E_Z\dots}{\dots})=E_X(\frac {1+\gamma^2X^2}{\dots})\ge \frac{[E_X\sqrt{1+\gamma^2X^2}]^2}{E_X\dots}=e^{-\gamma^2/2}[E_X\sqrt{1+\gamma^2X^2}]^2$, so the whole expression is at least $[E_X\sqrt{1+\gamma^2X^2}]^2-1\sim \gamma^2$. How does this agree with your conjectured $\gamma^4$ decay as $\gamma\to 0$? Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: @fedja (from my phone) I am not sure how you get this denominator for $n=1$. Since the square is outside of the $\mathbb{E}_Z$, the denominator should be 1 (as $\langle X,Z\rangle$ has expectation zero), shouldn't it?

Comment: You mean "the numerator"? I see. $E_Z[\rm{big\  formula}]^2$ is ambiguous: I interpreted it as the expectation of the square rather than the square of the expectation. So it should be the square of the expectation in $Z$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed (also, you're right, my above comment should read "numerator"). It's the square of the expectation (wrt $Z$). @fedja

Comment: I can also explicitly work out the cases $n=1$ and $(n,d)=(2,1)$ to get the $\gamma^4$ dependence, unless I made a mistake in my computations.

Comment: To the downvoter: is there something wrong with my question? How can I improve it?

Comment: For $d=1$ everything is trivially fine. The regime that bothers me is when both $d$ and $n$ are $c\gamma^{-2}$ with fixed (albeit small) $c>0$ and $\gamma\to 0$.

Comment: @fedja I agree $d=1$ is not the most... interesting regime. I just don't know how to approach the problem at the moment, and simulations with $d>1$ and $n > 1$ become computationally difficult quite fast.

Comment: @fedja The relation between $d$ and $\gamma$ you mention is the one I'm interested in, . Why do you think this regime (especially the one for $n$) is the possibly tricky one? (Note that for the "Gaussian analogue" of the question, where $Z$ is Gaussian and a few other details change accordingly, the $-1$ become something else which blows up to infinity when $n \nearrow \gamma^{-2}$)

Answer (score 1):

Something looks fishy at least with the first conjecture. Perhaps I'm again misinterpreting something, but the argument is as follows:

Consider $n=2$. Write $X^{(1)}=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt 2}, X^{(2)}=\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2}$. Then $X,Y$ are independent standard Gaussians in $\mathbb R^d$. Also
$$
E_Z[(1+\gamma\langle X^{(1)},Z\rangle)(1+\gamma\langle X^{(2)},Z\rangle)]=1+\gamma^2\langle X^{(1)},X^{(2)}\rangle
\\
=1+\frac{\gamma^2}2(\|X\|^2-\|Y\|^2)
$$
Now, since $\|Y\|^2$ is a sum of squares of $d$ independent Gaussians, it deviates from any fixed number by about $\sqrt d$ with constant probability, so the expectation $E_Y[E_Z[(1+\gamma\langle X^{(1)},Z\rangle)(1+\gamma\langle X^{(2)},Z\rangle)]^2]$ is at least $c\gamma^4d$ regardless of $X$ and the whole expression you are interested in is at least 
$$
-1+c\gamma^4d\left(E[\cosh(\gamma \sqrt 2 W)]E[\frac 1{\cosh(\gamma \sqrt 2 W)}]\right)^d
$$ 
but for fixed $\gamma$ and $d\to+\infty$, this is, clearly, exponential in $d$. What am I missing this time?

Comment: I have to read carefully what you wrote (what is $W$ in the last line?),but I may have been making a hidden assumption there. Namely (as used in the last part of my answer, dealing with the Gaussian variant) I am implicitly assuming $\gamma^2 d$ is bounded (as I get $e^{\gamma^2 d}\cdot \gamma^4 d$ as an upper bound), which is clearly not an assumption stated in my original post, but is something I'll have in my end application. I'll check if, under that assumption, what you wrote still provides a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, under that extra assumption $\gamma2 d \lesssim 1$, the last part indeed stays bounded, so things are consistent. I apologize for wasting your time by not stating that upfront.

Comment: @ClementC. $W$ is the standard Gaussian. Sorry for not stating that. Yeah, if $\gamma^2d$ is bounded, then the exponential growth gets tamed. OK, let me try to work it out under that assumption but expect more stupid questions :-)

Comment: @ClementC. One comes right away: is $n$ bounded too? (if so, what's the point of the $n$ factor in the proposed equivalence; if not, then I'm afraid that the exponential factor may still prevail as $n\to\infty$)

Comment: n is not bounded itself, but making the assumption $n \gamma^4 d \leq 1$ is fine. Long story short, this result is the last component to prove some sample complexity lower bound, and argue that a sample size $n\gtrsim 1/(d\gamma^4)$ is necessary. So if $n$ is larger, the job is done already.

Comment: @ClementC. So what is the actual game? Just to show that $\psi(\gamma,d,n)$ is small if $n\gamma^4 d$ is small or it is subtler than that?

Comment: It's not subtler than that, that's indeed the goal :) @fedja

Answer (score 0):

**Partial progress:** here is a proof for the analogous "Gaussian case" (i.e., $Z\sim N(\mathbf{0}_d, \mathbf{I}_d)$) and $n=2$. I was hoping to get some inspiration for it to handle the "Rademacher" $Z$ case I am interested in, *though it doesn't seem to be helpful after all*...

---

The goal is to bound an analogous quantity as (1), which for $n=2$ is
$$
\psi(\gamma,d,2) = \frac{e^{-\gamma^2 d}}{(1-2\gamma^2)^{d/2}}-2 + e^{\gamma^2d}\mathbb{E}_{XY}\left[ {\frac{\mathbb{E}_{Z}[ (1+\gamma\langle X,{Z}\rangle)(1+\gamma\langle Y,{Z}\rangle) ]^2}{ e^{\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y \rVert_2^2} } }\right]
$$
(the denominator changes because it comes from $\mathbb{E}_Z[e^{\gamma \langle\sum_{j=1}^n X^{(j)},Z\rangle}]$, and that expression changes between the Gaussian and Rademacher cases. Similarly for why the additive "-1" is now a less nice expression.)

We can expand and compute the numerator (before squaring) as
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}_{Z}\left[(1+\gamma\langle X, Z\rangle)(1+\gamma\langle Y, Z\rangle) \right]
  = \mathbb{E}_{Z}\left[1+\gamma\langle{X+Y,Z}\rangle + \gamma^2\langle X, Z\rangle\langle Y, Z\rangle \right]
  = 1+ \gamma^2\langle X, Y\rangle
\end{align*}
since $Z$ is Gaussian. From there, observing that $V := \frac{\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2}{2}$ is a $\chi^2(d)$ r.v., we get
\begin{align*}
  e^{-\gamma^2d }&(1+\psi(d ,\gamma,2))\\
  &= \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{ e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} (1+ \gamma^2\langle X, Y\rangle)^2 }]\\
  &= \mathbb{E}_{V}[{ e^{-\gamma^2 V} }] + 2\gamma^2 \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\langle X, Y\rangle e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] + \gamma^4\mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\langle X, Y\rangle^2e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] \\
  &\leq \mathbb{E}_{V}[{ e^{-\gamma^2 V} }] + 2\gamma^2 \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\langle X, Y\rangle e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] + \gamma^4\mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\langle X, Y\rangle^2}] \\
  &= \frac{1}{(1+2\gamma^2)^{d /2}} + \gamma^2 \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{(\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2 - \lVert X\rVert_2^2 - \lVert Y\rVert_2^2) e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] + d \gamma^4\,.
\end{align*}
The second term can be computed explicitly. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }]
  &= 2 \mathbb{E}_{V}[{V e^{-\gamma^2V} }] = \frac{2d }{(1+2\gamma^2)^{1+d /2}} \\
  \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{\lVert X\rVert_2^2e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] 
  &= \mathbb{E}_{X}[{\lVert X\rVert_2^2 \mathbb{E}_{Y}[{ e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }] }]
  = \mathbb{E}_{X}[{\lVert X\rVert_2^2 \prod_{i=1}^d \mathbb{E}_{Y}{ e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}(X_i+Y_i)^2} } }]\\
  &= {(1+\gamma^2)^{-d/2}}\mathbb{E}_{X}[{\lVert X\rVert_2^2e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2(1+\gamma^2)}\lVert X\rVert_2^2} }]
  = \frac{d (1+\gamma^2)}{(1+2\gamma^2)^{1+d /2}}
\end{align*}
from which the second term equals
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}_{XY}[{(\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2 - \lVert X\rVert_2^2 - \lVert Y\rVert_2^2) e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}\lVert X+Y\rVert_2^2} }]
  &= - \frac{2d \gamma^2}{(1+2\gamma^2)^{1+d /2}}\,.
\end{align*}
Overall, we get
\begin{align*}
  e^{-\gamma^2d }\left(2-\frac{e^{-\gamma^2 d}}{(1-2\gamma^2)^{d/2}}+\psi(d ,\gamma,2)\right)
  &\leq \frac{1}{(1+2\gamma^2)^{d /2}}\left(1- \frac{2d \gamma^4}{1+2\gamma^2}\right) + d \gamma^4
  \leq \frac{1}{(1+2\gamma^2)^{d /2}} + d \gamma^4\,,
\end{align*}
from which
\begin{align*}
  \psi(d ,\gamma,2)
  = O( d \gamma^4 )
\end{align*}
as long as $\gamma^2d = O(1)$.